# Can I inject @RootContext in ViewModel class?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-annotations, android-mvvm

I create MVVM android app, and I need context in my ViewModel class. I know that a ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context. But... 
does it apply also inject Context by @RootContext annotation?

I'm also wondering if I can use the context from a view object in the onClick method when I use DataBinding in ViewModel class.

Comment: why do you need context in your viewmodel and why not use AndroidViewModel ? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you can pass clicked view add your `onclick` param.

```xml
<View
...
android:onClick="@{(v)-> viewModel.modelOnClick(v)}"
...
/>
```

class `ViewModel`

```java
class ViewModel{
   public void modelOnClick(View v){
   }
}
```

so you have your clicked view in your model and can use it's context

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your answer. But what if I have to display for example deviceId String in the TextView? and I use AndroidAnnotations? Can I use @RootContext Context context in my ViewModel to get it? It works, but I want build clean architecture and I can't find any answer for it in network.

Comment: No it's not clean and it's not mvvm any more. if you want deviceId give it as viewmodel constructor param. Or when you need it your viewModel call view then view generate deviceId and call viewModel. The first one it so clean and testable